# How to compute the ls factor equation for USLE model in qgis grass r.mapcalc

Tags: qgis, map-algebra

To compute the LS factor for the USLE model, the following equation easily works in ArcGIS.  How can I perform the same in QGIS under GRASS `r.mapcalc`?

```
LSfator = Power (("flowaccNW") * resolution/22.1, 0.6) *
Power(Sin("slope_degnw") * 0.01745) / 0.09, 1.3
```